# Android, eclipse or AndroidStudio Sqlite Object helper

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite, android-studio

As you know in Android development, when you want to use `SQLite`, you must create another class as object that has this `table`'s columns.

it's very boring and wastes time to do that every time you create a new table. I'm wonder if there is a helper or a method or a tool to do that easier! in eclipse/Android Studio.

And also setting that Object's items with table's rows is a very long job!

I'm sure most of developers are looking for such a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider looking at an ORM such as [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/).

This tool comes with a generator that let you define your schema to generate these DAO and Model classes.

*A sample implementation I prepared for my co-workers: [GreendaoSample](https://github.com/Gorcyn/GreendaoSample)*